# Does "short integer solution" lattice problem admit hard instances with q=2?

Tags: computational-complexity, cryptography, integer-lattices

Let $q$ be a prime, $m,n$ be integers with $m>n$, and $\beta$ be a real number. Moreover, let $A$ be a matrix in $\mathbb Z^{n \times m}_q$. In the "short integer solution" (SIS) lattice problem, we are interested in **non-zero** integer vectors $\vec z \in \mathbb Z^m$ who satisfy two conditions:

1. Solution: $A\vec z \equiv \vec0 \pmod{q}$
2. Shortness: $\|\vec{z}\| \le \beta$

Note that for small-enough $\beta$'s, there might be no solution at all. Therefore, we will assume that $\beta$ is properly chosen to guarantee at least one solution.

For large values of $q$, there are worst-case lattice problems which reduce to the average-case SIS problem, and thereby establishing a firm ground for postulating that the SIS problem is hard-on-average (see, e.g., http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/wiki/index.php/Lattices#sis).

I'd like to know if there is any known result that postulates otherwise: Is it known that for $q=2$, the SIS problem is **NOT** hard-on-average? That is, by setting $q=2$, there's always an efficient algorithm which solves the SIS problem for random binary matrices $A \in \mathbb Z^{n \times m}_2$.

PS: I'm specially interested in the case where $q=2$, since it allows XOR operations instead of the less-efficient modular additions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $q=2$, one must have $\beta < 2$. However, such small $\beta$ does not guarantee an answer; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/456357/2420) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to build hard instances of the SIS Problem with $q=2$. Work the '''[Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)''' the other way: Build diagonal Matrix from a List of $2$s and $1$s. Then multiply arbitrary unitary matrices left and right to make a nontrivial problem. The resulting Matrix is a hard Problem, relative to the determinant, which rises quickly (exponentially), as soon as non-$1-Dimensions are added.